# A Question About the Surface of a Black Hole Singularity

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, quantum-gravity, event-horizon, singularities

In Kip Thorne's book, Black Holes and Time Warps, he states that the mass of the core of a star shrinks until quantum gravity takes over.  And then discusses that at this distance, the singularity cannot be distinguished from quantum foam.  I am confused.  Is he stating that the singularity is covered in quantum foam or does the mass shrink so small it becomes part of the quantum foam.  If it is the latter, how can the quantum gravity, affect the macroscopic world?

Is he discussing the surface is smooth, except for the fluctuations required by quantum gravity?

Sorry - I am not a scientist or student...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Thorne's book, on page 477, it says "Because all conceivable curvatures and topologies are permitted in side the singularity, no matter how wild, one says that the singularity is made from a probabilistic foam.  John Wheeler, who first argued that this must be the nature of space when the laws of quantum gravity hold sway, has called it quantum foam."

So what you are thinking of as a foam is really only a probabilistic foam.  This is just a way of saying that every possible state in the singularity is only a probability. (Takes you back to the probabilistic nature of any particle which is a discussion far beyond this answer).

But remember Thorne's central point of the chapter, that time does not exist at the singularity.  Space and time have separated from each other.  Time stops at the event horizon, but space continues to dilate all the way down to the singularity. This quantum foam is Wheeler's way of describing the situation of an unknowable, but only probabilistic, nature of the singularity.

Comment: That makes sense..  Thank you

Comment: No problem.  It was good for me to find that book because it answered some of my own thoughts about the black hole singularity.   Please click the checkmark beside my answer if it answered your question.

Comment: The statement that time ceases at the event horizon almost creates a paradox.  If time truly ceased then all matter meeting the event horizon would pool on it as a shell and never fall into towards the singularity.  I do understand though, that time "ceases" in the way that everything falling in past the event horizon is cut off from the rest of the universe (until the BH evaporates).

Comment: Now you have to think in two terms, first from the frame of the astronaut falling into the black hole, and then from our frame on Earth.  For the astronaut, his time continues as normal.  He thinks that time is continuing and he is falling into the black hole.  From our frame on earth, we see him slow down just outside the horizon, and then stop at the horizon.  Yes, there is a thought that nothing makes it past the horizon.  Everything just collects there, making the horizon bigger and bigger, probably until the end of the universe when it finally collapses.

Comment: On page 476, Thorne says "Quantum gravity then radically changes the character of spacetime......   It unglues space and time from each  other and then destroys time as a concept and destroys the definiteness of space.  Time ceases to exist."